# How to mask inputs on multi step form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using `mask.js` for my form masking, everything works except case when I builded multi step form with `vuejs`. Problem is that my mask works only on 1st step, any other step doesn't. Help me figure out how to make it workable on each step independently.

I use this way:

```
mounted() {
var numberMask = new IMask(
  document.getElementById('asd'),
  {
    mask: Number,
    min: 10,
    signed: false,
    scale: 4,
    radix: '.',
    max: 999999999999999,
});
}
```

Probably I should do something with `document.getElementById('asd')` but I'm beginner with javascript. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Mixing jQuery and VueJs... you're better off not doing that. They require very different ways of thinking. If you're new to javascript you're going to break your brain trying to do both at once. Pick one.

Comment: @geoidesic Ok, I'll keep this in mind, thanks man, I'll try to work with some vue solitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Mask-for-Vue instead of the jQuery Mask.js? https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/

Comment: Thanks for the url, I'm going to test it now.